# skip line in between \bigg\lbrace \bigg\rbrace does not work

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to write something like this:

[image]

I tried using this:

```
\bigg\lbrace {#1} \bigg\rbrace
```

My problem is: If I add some skip-lines ( using  \ \  ) nothing happens in the document. If someone knows has to do it or knows other way to do it, please tell me =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For larger-than-normal delimiters, you can use `\left`...`\right`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      subfields $E$ \\ of $K$ \\ containing $F$
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{array}{c}
      K \\ \vert \\ E \\ \vert \\ F
    \end{array}
  \right\}
  \quad
  \longleftrightarrow
  \quad
  \left\{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      subgroups $H$ \\ of $G$
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{array}{c}
      1 \\ \vert \\ H \\ \vert \\ G
    \end{array}
  \right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A short code with a single `blockarray`environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{blockarray}{\{\BAmultirow{2.2cm}c@{\enspace}c\}\BAmultirow{1cm}\{\BAmultirow{2.2cm}c@{\enspace}c\}}
  \parbox{1in}{\centering subfields $E$ \\ of $K$ \\ containing $F$} &    K  &  &\centerline{$  \longleftrightarrow $}& 
   \parbox{1in}{\centering subgroups $H$ \\ of $G$} &    1 & \\
   & \vert &  &  & & \lvert  &  \\
   & E &  &  &  & H &  \\
    & \vert  &  &  &  & \lvert  &  \\
     &  F &  &  &  & G & 
\end{blockarray}  \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]